# Which firmware version is correct for my CR-5 Pro with 4.2.2 main board?

Tags: firmware, creality-ender-5

My CR-5 Pro is brand new and has the V4.2.2 main board. Originally the "About" screen showed the following firmware version:

[image: Photo of the LCD for an Ender CR 5 Pro showing the firmware version]

When the machine went "catatonic" I re-flashed the main board based on instructions I found a [troubleshooting tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sBbwgcEadk4) on YouTube which resulted in the following:

[image: Photo of the LCD for an Ender CR 5 Pro showing the firmware version after being reflashed]

This software is not working properly. I'd like to find the file that was on the machine as purchased but nothing I've downloaded so far is what I want.